# Как правильно отфильтровать данные в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

При парсинге данных в одном случае переменные с данными есть, а в другом нет. К примеру:

```
    UserUrlApex = "https://public-api.tracker.gg/apex/v1/standard/profile/5/{}".format(outputApex)
    header = {"TRN-Api-Key": apiApex}
    reqUserApex = requests.get(UserUrlApex, headers=header)
    responApex = reqUserApex.json()
    test = responApex['data']
    apexLevel = responApex['data']['stats'][0]['value']
    apexRank = responApex['data']['stats'][0]['displayRank']
    apexKills = responApex['data']['stats'][1]['displayValue']
    apexDamage =  responApex['data']['stats'][2]['displayValue']
```

Если их нет, то просто отобразить `apexLevel`, ибо в противном случае вываливается 404 ошибка... И переменных `displayValue`, `displayRank` может попросто не быть.

Как правильно сделать проверку на наличие этих переменных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже было сказано, стоит проверять словари на наличие нужной информации. Это можно сделать без метода `dict.keys()`, оператор `in` успешно работает со словарями:

```
d = { 'pi': 3.1415 }
if 'e' in d:
    ...
```

Для проверки наличия нескольких ключей можно записать большой `if` с кучей `and`, а можно все нужные ключи записать в список и пройтись циклом:

```
all_right = True
need_keys = ['displayValue', 'displayRank']
data = ... # ваш словарь
for key in need_keys:
    if key not in data:
        # при необходимости можно также сохранить отсутствующий ключ
        all_right = False
        break

if all_right:
    # все ключи на месте
    ...
else:
    # чего-то не хватает
    ...
```

Т.к в примере смесь из список и словарей, то можно из `need_keys` сделать список тьюплов, и там прописать все нужные комбинации индексов и ключей... Но есть способ попроще.

---

Способ без предварительных проверок и в стиле Пайтона. Можно обернуть код в `try`:

```
all_right = True
try:
    test = responApex['data']
    apexLevel = responApex['data']['stats'][0]['value']
    apexRank = responApex['data']['stats'][0]['displayRank']
    apexKills = responApex['data']['stats'][1]['displayValue']
    apexDamage =  responApex['data']['stats'][2]['displayValue']

except (IndexError, KeyError) as ex:
    # Исключение IndexError кидает список, а KeyError словарь
    # при отсутствии данного индекса/ключа
    all_right = False

if all_right:
    # все ключи на месте
    ...
else:
    # чего-то не хватает
    ...
```

Comment: Спасибо за более детальное объяснение.

Answer (score 1):

Проверять словари на наличие ключей.

dict_name.keys() вернет все ключи словаря, переменные как вы их называете.

Следовательно примерно так все должна выглядеть проверка переменной displayValue:

```
if "displayValue" in apexKills["data"]["stats"][2].keys():
    ...
```

Comment: Теперь другя ошибка ```TypeError: string indices must be integers```

Comment: Оператор `in` успешно работает с самими словарями, применять метод `.keys()` не обязательно.